# Is there a word that encompasses the meaning of both "sort" and "filter"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Filtering seems to be like restricting things out of a group of things, while sorting is keeping the group of things the same but changing the ordering. Wondering if there's a word that can classify this "change of a grouping in some fashion

Comment: How about "classify"?

Comment: How are you intending to use it? Is it a label for a group of filter and sort options?

Comment: You should probably read Kernighan and Plauger, or Kernighan and Pike. You're talking about software tools, and they have been very thoroughly thought through.

Comment: @JohnLawler That is an interesting read, apologies for not clarifying but yes it was meant more in a programming perspective sort/filter. I guess I'll keep the terms separated instead of trying to create some word up to group them together

Answer (score 0):

A [*sieve*](http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/collegiate/sieve) is

> a device with meshes or perforations through which finer particles of
>   a mixture (as of ashes, flour, or sand) of various sizes may be passed
>   to separate them from coarser ones

To *sieve* (the verb form) is to perform this operation, which sorts and filters at the same time.

Comment: Winnowing has a similar meaning (and origin) but it's more obscure. It has the advantage of not also being a name for a common item that might confuse people.